# Finding a Jquery Tab by attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I need to find the tab index and id of a tab that has two particular attributes. Here's an example tab:

```
<div id="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;" tabcounter="2" symbol="GOOG" exchange="NASDAQ">
```

In this case, I want it to spit out the index as well as "tabs-2" when it identifies that the symbol is "GOOG" and the exchange is "NASDAQ".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div[symbol=GOOG][exchange[NASDAQ]').attr('tabindex')
```

it should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

To select an element based on attributes, use the "attributes selector"

```
var elem = $('[symbol="GOOG"][exchange="NASDAQ"]')
```

then to get the ID and index

```
var id    = elem.prop('id');
var index = elem.index();
```

Comment: This helped me learn it, but is missing a div right after the $('

Comment: @user1357015 - You generally don't need the `div`, as selectors are read right to left, and including the tagname is inefficient, unless you for some reason have multiple elements with the same attributes and **have** to filter on tagname as well.